# Python: IndentationError: expected an indented block

Tags: python, indentation

I know this is a common question but I've got to reiterate this one because I've used the "proven" methods and none work. At first I figured it would be a spacing issue as atom (the text editor I'm using) at default has 2 spaces in each tab. Updated that to 4 and re-tabbed everything and got the same error. I went back and just put 4 spaces before every line that needed to be indented and that didn't work as well. Any suggestions?

[My Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pj5sE.png)

Comment: This code is directly out of a book for learning python via 2012.

Comment: From the screenshot I am seeing a line that is not indented.

Comment: You need to indent line 25 once more because the previous line is an IF statement

Comment: same for your next if at line 33

Answer (score 0):

You need to indent line 25 by 4 more space as it's within an if clause.

Answer (score 0):

Exactly as the error suggests, line 25 needs to be idented, but it is not. It is the body of the `if` statement above.

```
if True:
    pass
    # if body
```

Regardless how many line your `if` condition is, after `:` you'll need to ident.